# How to get to a specific row in a ListView on Android using the row tag?

Tags: android, android-listview

I've got a ListView which gets a list of files. It then goes to the `drawable` resources and loads the files. Each filename is saved in a holder which is saved in the row tag, such as:

```
row.setTag(holder);
```

Where the holder is of this type:

```
static class RowHolder {
    ImageView img;
    String resourceName;
    int position;
}
```

Where the resourceName is the filename used to load the img.

I want to change the code so that I load the files from a remote server, thus - I've got 2 options:

1. Load each file, save to disk and then add to the ListView
2. Send to the ListView a list of all files that will be downloaded, show a 'loading' sign for each row, and when the file is downloaded - show it in its' place in the ListView.

I'm trying to pursue the second option. The first part is easy - just show a loading image. But how would you find that row again (by the `resourceName` field of the row tag) and then update the image after it has been downloaded?

Many Thanks!

Comment: Did you just answer your own question: '(by the resourceName field of the row tag)'?

Comment: But how would you do that?

Comment: my sugestion is to use lazy list and load images one per download

Comment: Sounds great - how would one do that? :)

Comment: please create android sample demo (for eclipse) `File>New...>Other...>Android Sample Project>` let's say `Android 2.3.3>ApiDemos>Finish`. Compile and run on your phone, find out lazy list, and then find it in project this code and lean it :) Example in running apk is: `Views>Lists>13. Slow adapter`